# Regex for a series of known words separated by periods, optionally with number between

Tags: regex

I am having a hard time figuring out the right regex for a problem I'm trying to solve. It does not need to be concise, or even a single expression for all cases. Some examples of what I'd be looking to match:

```
my_word
my_word.0
my_word.1
my_word.0.my_other_word
my_word.my_other_word
my_word.my_other_word.0
```

`my_word` and `my_other_word` are order dependent, and must be an exact match. Everything will be delimited with `.`, and there may or may not be numbers between them with the same delimiter. There may be an arbitrarily long list of words, and the numbers can be any length. two numbers will not follow each other, but two words might. I understand this may require a series of regex expressions, and that's fine. As long as the pattern is clear, I can probably autogenerate the regex when I have the list of words to check for.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add few meaningful examples of strings that ***should not*** match?

Comment: From a comment below: `some_random_word_that_is_not_my_word.0` would not be a match. I.e. `my_word` and `my_other_word` are not arbitrary sequences of characters, but rather should be exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following regex pattern:

```
^(?!.*\.\d+\.\d+)(?:[A-Za-z_]+|[0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[A-Za-z_]+|[0-9]+))*$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation:

- `^` from the start of the input
- `(?!.*\.d+\.\d+)` assert that two digits separated by dot do NOT occur
- `(?:[A-Za-z_]+|[0-9]+)` match a word (letters + underscore) or number
- `(?:\.(?:[A-Za-z_]+|[0-9]+))*` then match zero or more words/numbers, separated by dots
- `$` end of the input

Comment: That was quick! I like that you were able to explain the components coherently, demonstrate a match against all of the cases mentioned and include test for what should not match as well. Top notch answer!

Comment: Looking a little bit deeper, I have one comment on this solution: I would ideally like to match exact words (not just any word) so something like `some_random_word_that_is_not_my_word.0` would not be a match. I.e. `my_word` and `my_other_word` are not arbitrary sequences of characters, but rather should be exact matches

Comment: @Brendan I have updated my answer per these additional requirements.  Now only letter words (with optional underscores) and separate numbers are allowed.